# Custom text option on configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options

So here's an interesting requirement.

We're required to sell a item that comes in different sizes/colors and so for that a configurable product works great. However, now we want to add the ability for a customer to add their custom text to the product.

Is this possible in Magento by default (or via some ready made plugin)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding custom options?

In the product edit screen menu there is a `Custom Options` category. From there, click `Add New Option` and you can add the title, input type, choose if it is required and pick the sort order from there.

Comment: yes, but that does not work if yo try adding it to a configurable item

Comment: Does doesn't work mean that you aren't seeing it on the frontend?

Are you adding this to the simple product in the configurable set? If so, are you able to add it on the main configurable product to fit your needs?